# awaiting async method in consumer using BlockingCollection as queue

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asynchronous, blockingcollection

I am working on a server side console application which receives data from multiple WCF services, does some work on it and then forwards the results to an IIS server over a single connection using SignalR.

I tried to implement this using the producer consumer pattern where the WCF services are the producers and the class sending the data using SignalR is the consumer. For the queue I used the [BlockingCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997371(v=vs.110).aspx).

However, when using await/async to send the data in the consumer's while loop gets stuck until all other threads have finished adding data to the queue.

For testing purposes I have replaced the code actually sending the data with a `Task.Delay(1000).Wait();` or `await Task.Delay(1000);` which both get stuck as well.
A simple `Thread.Sleep(1000);` seems to work just fine, leading me to think the asynchronous code is the problem.

So my question is: Is there something preventing the asynchronous code being completed in the while loop? What am I missing?

I'm starting the consumer thread like this:

```
new Thread(Worker).Start();
```

And the consumer code:

```
private void Worker()
{
    while (!_queue.IsCompleted)
    {
        IMobileMessage msg = null;
        try
        {
            msg = _queue.Take();
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException)
        {
        }

        if (msg != null)
        {
            try
            {
                Trace.TraceInformation("Sending: {0}", msg.Name);
                Thread.Sleep(1000); // <-- works
                //Task.Delay(1000).Wait(); // <-- doesn't work
                msg.SentTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
                Trace.TraceInformation("X sent at {1}: {0}", msg.Name, msg.SentTime);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                TraceException(e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Blocking and async not friends. If you're mixing `async` with `BlockingCollection<T>`, you should strongly consider ditching `BlockingCollection<T>` and taking a look at TPL Dataflow. The `BufferBlock<T>` is a good starting point and is approximately equivalent to `BlockingCollection<T>`, but dataflow has plenty more to offer for producer/consumer scenarios. Take time to learn about it. It's worth it.

Comment: Nice, thank you very much, I will look into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As spender correctly pointed out, `BlockingCollection` (as the name implies) is intended only for use with blocking code, and does not work so well with asynchronous code.

There are async-compatible producer/consumer queues, such as `BufferBlock<T>`. In this case, I would think `ActionBlock<T>` would be even better:

```
private ActionBlock<IMobileMsg> _block = new ActionBlock<IMobileMsg>(async msg =>
{
  try
  {
    Trace.TraceInformation("Sending: {0}", msg.Name);
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    msg.SentTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
    Trace.TraceInformation("X sent at {1}: {0}", msg.Name, msg.SentTime);
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
    TraceException(e);
  }
});
```

This replaces your entire consuming thread and main loop.

Comment: I added the code you suggested replacing my consumer and queue and also read your excellent posts on your blog about the TPL dataflow and it looks like it works but I can't confirm yet as now my producer timer stops after 2 ticks each time. But I guess that's something new. I'll accept your answer as soon as I can confirm it's working! Thanks!

Comment: For some reason I can't seem to get it to work... My producer checks if there are new messages from the WCF service every second (using `Task.Delay(1000);` in a loop and posts them to the ActionBlock if there are. Depending on what times I use in the action block's delay and the producer's delay, everything works just fine, stops completely, or only posts messages to the blocks buffer but doesn't process them anymore. Any obvious reason you can't use the actionblock with an async while loop in the producer?

Comment: @J.Neijt: No, an async producer works fine. If your `TraceException` throws an exception, that would stop the block from working.

Comment: Unfortunately I was unable to fix the problem and as time ran out I had to go back to a previous version and I have changed the architecture now. Probably there were some other problems going on as well... So I can't confirm but I can see your answer being the solution to the problem described and I'll be happy to accept it and thank you very much for your help anyways!